# How to handle click event in Visual Studio Code message box?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

According to the API docs, a Message box can take a second argument: an array of strings which act as actions on the message box (which normally just has a single close button/action):

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_window

```ts
showInformationMessage(message: string, ...items: string[]): Thenable<string>
```

So I tried this:

```ts
vscode.window.showInformationMessage('hello world', ['test','taco','cheeseburger'], function(value){
  console.log(value + " was clicked");
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I get the message box along with a Close button like normal. But then to the left of the close button appears to be another single button with no text or title.

Another function definition is:

```ts
showInformationMessage<T extends MessageItem>(message: string, ...items: T[]): Thenable<T>
```

So I tried something like this:

```ts
let message: vscode.MessageItem = { title: 'testing' };
vscode.window.showInformationMessage('hello', [message], function(value){
  console.log(value + " was clicked");
});
```

But that doesn't seem to work either. There is a scarce amount of documentation on this so I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```js
vscode.window
  .showInformationMessage('hello', 'test', 'taco', 'cheeseburger')
  .then(selection => {
    console.log(selection);
  });
```

or

```js
vscode.window
  .showInformationMessage('hello', ...['test', 'taco', 'cheeseburger'])
  .then(selection => {
    console.log(selection);
  });
```

Both result in a dialog that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I figured this out recently. Thank you. Kind of weird you put in an arbitrary number of items instead of an array of arbitrary length.